# Error in enum data type while uploading intent dialogflow

Tags: javascript, enums, dialogflow-es

I am trying to upload my intent everything is working fine, i am writing script in V2 and everything works but for parameter webhookState data type is enum ( [here] ) and we have to enter following of the three values ( [here][1]) now when i enter any one and try to upload it shows.

" Unable to load file: SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 98 "

now when I pass WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED(or any one) in quotes code uploads successfully (because as per my knowledge it treats it as string and gets executed) and intent is created for my agent but webhook remains off and also training phrases are not there, i am certain that the parameter webhookState is not being activated when i pass in quotes(because of above mentioned reason) Same is the case with rest, like when i try to put in type of training phrases.

```
 {
  "name": "Warehouse_Management",
  "displayName": "Warehouse_Management",
  "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED_FOR_SLOT_FILLING" ,
  "priority": 50000,
  "isFallback": false,
  "mlDisabled": false,
  "trainingPhrases": [
    {
      "name":"Try1" ,
      "type": "EXAMPLE",
      "parts": [
    {
        "text": "for",
        "userDefined": true
    },
    {
        "text": "warehouse",
        "entityType": "@Properties",
        "alias": "Properties",
        "userDefined": true
    },
    {
        "text": "management",
        "userDefined": true
    }


  ]

    },
    {
      "name":"Try2" ,
      "type": "EXAMPLE",
      "parts": [
    {
        "text": "i want app for ",
        "userDefined": true
    },
    {
        "text": "warehouse",
        "alias": "Properties",
        "entityType": "@Properties",
        "userDefined": true
    }


  ]

    }
  ],
  "outputContexts": [
    {
        "name": "Yes",
        "lifespanCount": 2

    },
    {
        "name": "No",
        "lifespanCount": 2

    },
    {
        "name": "Device_Integration",
        "lifespanCount": 2

    }
  ],
  "resetContexts": false,
  "parameters": [
    {
        "name": "Properties",
        "displayName": "Properties",
        "value": "$parameter_name",
        "entityTypeDisplayName": "@Properties",
        "mandatory": false,
        "isList": true
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
        {
       "text":"This is sample response"

        }


  ],
  "rootFollowupIntentName": "root",
  "parentFollowupIntentName": "parent"
}
```

Please NOTE that in the attached Json i have put it in quotes so it would get successfully executed and will create intent.

Comment: Strings *must* be enclosed in quotes for JSON to be valid. Also note that your description is missing links.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to be valid JSON, the enum value should be wrapped in quotes. It's expecting the enum value as a String.